# What size diode do I need

Tags: diodes

I'm working on a car project to allow for a 12vdc ignition system w/out cutting factory wire and bypassing the factory 9v ballast resistor wire. I'm using 3 cube relays to allow for a backup relay. Without a diode, there would be "pinball" effect when/if the Primary relay fails, and the [image]Backup relay powers the ignition buss. So the diode only comes into play when the Backup relay powers the buss and stops power to the Switch over relay. I'd like to give the buss 10amps for anything else that needs power during cranking and run.

Comment: You'd want a diode rated for over 10Amps then. Note that 10 Amps running through a diode is going to make it hot, so it will need to be heatsinked - just like the diodes in an alternator. In fact alternator diodes might be a good choice. Personally I'd be putting in an electronic ignition system and the ballast resistor just disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into alternator diodes. As far as the electronic ignitions go, my Pertronix uses 12v, my old Mustang uses a resistor wire in the dash wiring that feeds the ignition lead and would drop voltage to 9v, so it's not like the ceramic firewall mounted ballast resistor you would see in old Chevy's. Could you tell how you determined 10 amps, or is it because I want the buss 10 amps? I'm asking to learn for any future projects.

Comment: The diode must be at least rated for the current you require - preferably more. If your circuit wants 10Amps,then you would choose a diode with a current rating higher than that, maybe 15A or 25A. Generally the higher the current, the larger and more expensive the diode is.